# Eclipse - file search containing text - regex to include whitespace combinations?

Tags: regex, eclipse

In Eclipse, if I search for `charCode == 44`in File Search>Containing Text, I miss out on all of the results that might have different spaces e.g. `charCode== 44`, `charChode ==44` etc

Is there a way (I imagine with would require the Regular Expression option) to include the whitespace combinations in the search text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the regular expression

```
charCode\s*==\s*44
```

**Explanation:**
`\s` means any space character (space, tab, ...). The `*` means zero or more occurrences of the previous literal.

**Note:** Be sure to check the *Regular expression* checkbox to the right of the search field.

Comment: @Stefan_Winkler Does the star mean not mean zero or more occurrences?

Comment: @Brian B - it does indeed. Corrected my answer. Thanks for the heads up ;-)